# Laravel 8 submitting form does nothing when clicked

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I made an reminder form in Laravel, the reminder should save to datebase with related task id. but every time I click the submit button, nothing happens and also no errors are showing.

Here is my routes

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task}/edit/reminder/add', [ReminderController::class, 'add'])->name('reminder.add');
Route::post('/tasks/edit/reminder/save', [ReminderController::class, 'store'])->name('reminder.store');
```

Here is my controller

```
class ReminderController extends Controller
{
    public function add(Task $task)
    {
      abort_if(Gate::denies('task_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

      return view('tasks.taskReminderAdd');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $postData = $this->validate($request, [

          'reminder' => 'required|min:3',
          'reminder_date' => 'required|date',
          'task_id' => 'required|exists:task,id'

        ]);

        $postData['user_id'] = $request->user()->id;
        $postData['status'] = 'pending';

        $task=Task::find($postData['task_id']);
        $task->reminders()->create($postData);

        return redirect()->route('task.edit',[$task]);
    }
}
```

Here is my part of html

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('reminder.store','postData') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                      <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">

                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                          <label for="reminder" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Reminder</label>
                          <input type="text" name="reminder" id="reminder" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                                 value="{{ old('reminder', '') }}" />
                          @error('reminder')
                              <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                          @enderror
                      </div>
```

Comment: "*every time I click the submit button*" - what submit button? You have not shown us any button. What debugging have you tried?  In your browser's devtools, click on the network tab - does the POST actually happen?  If yes, click the request - are the values sent as you expect? What is the server response?  Why do you have`'postData'` in the form action?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> form method="post" action="{{ route('reminder.store','postData') }}"
> ```

Your question is lacking information needed. However, I highly doubt that you are missing `@csrf` token in your form or wrong HTML form structure. Before continuing, consider cheking out [@csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) and adding form strucutre into your question. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I have editted my post. Actually I was already put a csrf token.

Comment: @DoğancanKabaoğlu There is no button you provided in the form...